# lmer for simple unpooled statistics

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I have one vector of predictor, one vector of response, and two columns of categories, each has two possible classifications.

I tried to create an unpooled linear model using lmer, but I get conflicting results.

1. lmer(response ~ predictor + (1 | category1:category2), data) gives me a singular model
2. lmer(response ~ (predictor | category1:category2), data) gives me non-singular model

what is the difference between the two? each class should have its own slope and intercepts.

Comment: What do you mean by 'unpooled'?  Also your two models are different in that the first has a random intercept only and the second has random intercept and slope.

Comment: Unpooled as in there's no hierarchy in the categories (its gender and method of transport (public vs private).                                                                    What is the difference of #2 with lmer(response ~ predictor + (1 + predictor | category1 ) + (1 + predictor | category2)? I just want to create a linear model using lmer with 1 vector of response and 1 vector of predictor with 2 vectors of categories which has no hierarchy or orderings. Also, thank you for respondng!

Answer (score 0):

"Unpooled" typically refers to a "fixed effects" model. It means that each category is given it's own unique intercept. These models are typically estimated using `lm`, not `lmer`, the latter estimating "partially pooled" or "random effects" models. In order to estimate an unpooled model on your data, I would suggest the following `lm`:

`unpooled <- lm(response ~ predictor + category1 + category2 + category1:category2, data)`

This will give you the following interpretations for each regression coefficients you see in `summary(unpooled)`:

```
(Intercept)         - the adjusted response mean for individuals with 0 values on category 1 and 2 
category 1          - the mean difference, relative to the (Intercept), for individuals with a 1 on category 1 and a 0 on category 2.
category 2          - the mean difference, relative to the (Intercept), for individuals with a 1 on category 2 and a 0 on category 1.
category1:category2 - the mean difference, relative to the (Intercept), for individuals with a 1 on both category 1 and category 2
```

By addition and subtraction of these coefficients, you can reconstruct the intercept for each of the four groups. For example the intercept for category 1 is equal to the addition of the coefficients for (Intercept) and category1.

Comment: I think what I need is cross classification model for this problem. Unpooled assuming that each of the category doesn't have any relationship with one another isn't it? However, I'd like to build a model that also take into account how these categories could affect the model despite the hierarchy/orderings doesn't matter (category 1 is not a subset of category 2, and vice versa). Thank you for the reply, I'll try your suggestion and report back